# Duplicate .setText code for various button ID's

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

My program dynamically creates a total of (4) QLineEdit widgets in a column and the number of column changes on users input. A file dialog button that is attached to an ID, will be in the last row of each column. So when a button is clicked .setText will fill out the corresponding columns QLineEdit widgets.

The (4) QLineEdit widgets are being put into a list called self.Widgets. I am using .setText to add input values to them.

My question is, if I have multiple buttons/multiple ID's, and the .setText format for the widgets are identical for each button, but each button ID uses a different range of widgets in the self.Widget list, is there a way to shorten the method without having to copy and paste the .setText code and change indexes for each button ID?

---

Button ID (0) uses widgets 0-3 in self.Widgets

Button ID (1) uses widgets 4-7 in self.Widgets

Button ID (2) uses widgets 8-11 in self.Widgets

Button ID (3) uses widgets 12-15 in self.Widgets

and so on..

---

There is will be a maximum of 10 buttons being used, so the # of ID's range from 0 to 10. And the buttons only set text for 4 widgets in each column.

Code:

```
@pyqtSlot(int)
def inText(self, button_or_id):
    if isinstance(button_or_id, int):
        if button_or_id == 0:
            File= self.File()
                if File:
                    StagNum,SND,DND,PCVS,PCVD,CPVD,CPVS,PM = File
                        self.Widgets[0].setText(str(('{0}'.format(StagNum))))
                        self.Widgets[1].setText(str(('{0} / {1}'.format(SND, DND))))
                        self.Widgets[2].setText(str(('{0} / {1} / {2} / {3}'.format(PCVS, PCVD, CPVD, CPVS))))
                        self.Widgets[3].setText(str(PM))
```

Example of what it will look like if I don't shorten it:

```
@pyqtSlot(int)
def inText(self, button_or_id):
    if isinstance(button_or_id, int):
        if button_or_id == 0:
            File= self.File()
                if File:
                    StagNum,SND,DND,PCVS,PCVD,CPVD,CPVS,PM = File
                        self.Widgets[0].setText(str(('{0}'.format(StagNum))))
                        self.Widgets[1].setText(str(('{0} / {1}'.format(SND, DND))))
                        self.Widgets[2].setText(str(('{0} / {1} / {2} / {3}'.format(PCVS, PCVD, CPVD, CPVS))))
                        self.Widgets[3].setText(str(PM))
        if button_or_id == 1:
            File= self.File()
                if File:
                    StagNum,SND,DND,PCVS,PCVD,CPVD,CPVS,PM = File
                        self.Widgets[4].setText(str(('{0}'.format(StagNum))))
                        self.Widgets[5].setText(str(('{0} / {1}'.format(SND, DND))))
                        self.Widgets[6].setText(str(('{0} / {1} / {2} / {3}'.format(PCVS, PCVD, CPVD, CPVS))))
                        self.Widgets[7].setText(str(PM))
        if button_or_id == 2:
            File= self.File()
                if File:
                    StagNum,SND,DND,PCVS,PCVD,CPVD,CPVS,PM = File
                        self.Widgets[8].setText(str(('{0}'.format(StagNum))))
                        self.Widgets[9].setText(str(('{0} / {1}'.format(SND, DND))))
                        self.Widgets[10].setText(str(('{0} / {1} / {2} / {3}'.format(PCVS, PCVD, CPVD, CPVS))))
                        self.Widgets[11].setText(str(PM))
        if button_or_id == 3:
            File= self.File()
                if File:
                    StagNum,SND,DND,PCVS,PCVD,CPVD,CPVS,PM = File
                        self.Widgets[12].setText(str(('{0}'.format(StagNum))))
                        self.Widgets[13].setText(str(('{0} / {1}'.format(SND, DND))))
                        self.Widgets[14].setText(str(('{0} / {1} / {2} / {3}'.format(PCVS, PCVD, CPVD, CPVS))))
                        self.Widgets[15].setText(str(PM))
        if button_or_id == 4:
            File= self.File()
                if File:
                    StagNum,SND,DND,PCVS,PCVD,CPVD,CPVS,PM = File
                        self.Widgets[16].setText(str(('{0}'.format(StagNum))))
                        self.Widgets[17].setText(str(('{0} / {1}'.format(SND, DND))))
                        self.Widgets[18].setText(str(('{0} / {1} / {2} / {3}'.format(PCVS, PCVD, CPVD, CPVS))))
                        self.Widgets[19].setText(str(PM))
```

and so on until, button_or_id == 10 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I well understand your method, you should use that to simplify:

```
@pyqtSlot(int)
def inText(self, button_or_id):
    if not isinstance(button_or_id, int):
        return

    if button_or_id < 0 or button_or_id > 10: # min/max valid id
        return

    base = button_or_id * 4
    File= self.File()
    if not File:
        return

    StagNum, SND, DND, PCVS, PCVD, CPVD, CPVS, PM = File
    self.Widgets[base].setText(str(('{0}'.format(StagNum))))
    self.Widgets[base + 1].setText(str(('{0} / {1}'.format(SND, DND))))
    self.Widgets[base + 2].setText(str(('{0} / {1} / {2} / {3}'.format(PCVS, PCVD, CPVD, CPVS))))
    self.Widgets[base + 3].setText(str(PM))
```

I exit method with return on each error case to remove a lot of indentation, after I compute a base value for your new column.